# "It's working for me": correct?

Tags: expressions

This question came to my mind, while working with StackOverflow. Whenever a solution to a question is posted, I usually see people writing:
*"It's working for me".*
I somehow do not like this expression. It also forces me to think, whether it is a grammatically correct expression?

I personally would write:
*"It's working in my case".*

Comment: [The "Works on My Machine" Certification Program](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/the-works-on-my-machine-certification-program.html)

Comment: Voting to close. This sounds like peeving about this expression. The expression is grammatical.

Comment: Why do you think it is not grammatically correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"It's working for me" is clear and correct; it is analogous to idiomatic *[works for me](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/works+for+me)*.  I think many people will find "It's working in my case" clear too, unless they dwell on it and start wondering if the case you refer to is a suitcase, a toolbox, *etc.*

An acceptable alternative is "It works for the examples I tried."

Comment: I thank you for providing the link, I find it good!

Comment: I think OP's example is far more literal than the typical usage of *works for me* and thus isn't really "analogous." The idiom just means *that's fine with me*, while OP's example seems to be in reference to a program/bit of code/whatever functioning properly.

Comment: @onomatomaniak - It is quite analogous to say of some code (or coding situation) either "That works for me" or "That code works for the examples I tried", the former being used in "typical" form.  A relevant sense of *analogous*:  "bearing some resemblance or proportion"